# Div inside fieldset using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a div inside another main div dynamically using JS. Now I have created fieldset and a legend, and I want to add main div inside fieldset, but it's not working.

```
 var maindiv= document.createElement('div');
               maindiv.setAttribute("id","TextBoxesGroup"+vl);
               var secdiv=document.createElement('div');
               secdiv.setAttribute("id","TextBoxDiv1"+vl)
               maindiv.appendChild(secdiv);
                var ipt=document.createElement("input");
                ipt.setAttribute("type","text");
                ipt.setAttribute("id","textbox1"+vl);
                secdiv.appendChild(ipt);
```

For fieldset:

```
var fld=document.createElement("fieldset");
             fld.style.border="1px solid black";
             var lgd=document.createElement("legend");
             lgd.innerHTML=txt;
             fld.appendChild(lgd);
```

Now I tried:    `fld.appendChild(maindiv);` But it's not working. Is there any way of doing this?

Update:

Part of line I missed to update:

```
document.getElementById("updt").appendChild(maindiv);
```

The division inside another div displays properly. Only fieldset when I add it's not working.

Comment: How do you know its not working? You did not append it to body

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Try to be more specific.

Comment: you should create a codepen or a jsfiddle or plnkr template to help others resolve it fast.

Comment: Thank you all for response. I updated question.

Comment: use this `document.getElementById("updt").appendChild(fld)` insteads of this `document.getElementById("updt").appendChild(maindiv)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check this fiddle link [FIddle][1]. assign the fieldset to a parent element.
ex : i included the body as a parent for fieldset.


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Abhilash1994/7Ltyc8zx/
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The mistake I made was i appeded maindiv instead of fieldset. Thank you so much.